# Google play app rejected Require that users accept the app's terms of use and/or user policy before users can create or upload UGC

Tags: google-play

My app is rejected for this reason **Require that users accept the app's terms of use and/or user policy before users can create or upload UGC**

I have one chatroom in the app for all users to discuss a topic and its open without registration .. **What should I do to fix this?**

Comment: Facing similar issue, let me know if you have any findings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Require that users accept the app's terms of use and/or user policy before users can create or upload UGC
```

As the sentence say, you should:

1. Write your app's terms of use and/or user policy.
2. Show popup or activity to show that terms of use and/or user policy.
3. Allow user to chat after user check agree button at the end.
4. Build app and submit your app again.

Check out some demo you can follow here:
[image]

[image: https://termsfeed.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ebay-android-app-register-account-screen-agree-user-agreement-privacy-notice.jpg]
[image]
[image]